# iOS RxSwift - testing with RxTest and TestScheduler does not end / terminate test case

Tags: swift, unit-testing, rx-swift, swift4.2, rxtest

I'm trying to understand how to correctly use `TestScheduler` from `RxTest 4.2` for `RxSwift 4.2`.

**How do I correctly create TestScheduler and pass it events which would terminate the scheduler after all events are executed?**

The code below goes into infinite loop upon starting the test scheduler. Because it keeps looping synchronously, I have no opportunity to stop the scheduler from the test

```
    var testScheduler: TestScheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)

    let stateObserver = testScheduler.createObserver(Bool.self)
    subject.outputRelay.bind(to: stateObserver).disposed(by: bag)

    let events = [next(1,true), next(10,false)]
    let hotObservable = testScheduler.createHotObservable(events)

    //direct events to the given relay
    hotObservable.bind(to: subject.inputRelay).disposed(by: bag)

    testScheduler.start() //infinite loop

//do not get called
    XCTAssertEqual(stateObserver.events, [next(0, InterfaceState.started)])
    testScheduler.stop()
```

I've narrowed the issued down to this method call within `TestScheduler`. It seems there's something wrong with the subscription disposal

```
 func findNext() -> VirtualSchedulerItem<VirtualTime>? {
        while let front = _schedulerQueue.peek() {
            if front.isDisposed {
                //this never gets called
                _schedulerQueue.remove(front)
                continue
            }

            return front
        }

        return nil
    }
```

Comment: See https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1997#issuecomment-498433844 for why this is happening

Answer (score 1):

What I do in this cases is schedule a block in specific time that I know all test should have finish and there stop the subscription. I think in your case should something like this:

```
//...
let hotObservable = testScheduler.createHotObservable(events)
let disposable = hotObservable.bind(to: subject.inputRelay)
testScheduler.scheduleAt(1) {
     disposable.dispose()
}
testScheduler.start()
XCTAssertEqual(stateObserver.events, [next(0, InterfaceState.started)])
//...
```